# Number of solutions for $x\equiv a^2\pmod p$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be some prime number.
>
> How many numbers $x\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$ exist such that $x\equiv a^2\pmod p$ for $a\in\Bbb{Z}$?

I tried to use some methods in order to answer it and checked some numerical examples, but could not conclude what should be the answer.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Exactly half the non-zero residues are squares (assuming $p$ is odd).  The map $\left( \frac {\mathbb Z}{p\mathbb Z}\right)^*$ to itself given by squaring has kernel $\{\pm 1\}$.  You can read about the general theory [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)

Comment: @lulu: I think anybody capable of understanding your comment wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Comment: @TonyK  You might be right about that.  My main thought was to include the link.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be a generator of cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Then try to show that $x$ is quadratic residue (i.e. $x\equiv a^{2}(mod \,\,p)$ for some $a$ if and only if $gx$ is not. Then the number of quadratic residues and quadratic non-residues are same as $(p-1)/2$.

Comment: "for some p" should be replaced by "for some a"

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

All odd prime $p$ admits a primitive root which is a generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbb F_p^*$ (maybe more, for example $11$ has four,  $2,6,7$ and $8$). So if $a$ is a primitive root of $\mathbb F_p$ one has 
$$\mathbb F_p=\{a,a^2,a^3,a^4,....,a^{p-1}\}\cup\{0\}=\mathbb F_p^*\cup\{0\}$$

It is clear that $a^2,a^4,a^8,....,a^{p-1}$ are squares. There are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the numbers $1^2,2^2,\ldots,(p-1)^2$. There are $p-1$ entries in the list, and each number occurs exactly twice (unless $p=2$), because $a^2\equiv b^2 \bmod p$ if and only if $a \equiv \pm b \bmod p$. So this list contains exactly half of the non-zero residues $\bmod p$. Add in $0$, and you get a total of $\frac12(p+1)$ numbers.

These numbers are called the *quadratic residues* $\bmod p$.